# Inject dependency based off of requesting class type

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have a the following situation:

```
class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);

    ... methods ...
}
```

and I think that it would be nice if I could inject my logger instead of creating it in the class i.e.

```
class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    @Inject
    private Logger logger;

    ... methods ...
}
```

Does anyone know if this sort of thing is possible with the Guice? I have been using Guice for a while now but can't think of a way to base the injection of a field off of the requesting class's class type.

Comment: I once implemented such a [thing](https://github.com/tavianator/sangria/blob/master/sangria-contextual/src/main/java/com/tavianator/sangria/contextual/ContextSensitiveBinder.java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not only possible but is even described in details in the Guice Wiki under *Custom Injections*. For complete example with log4j and all explanations have a look [here](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/CustomInjections). I've adapted this example in one of my [little projects](https://github.com/luchob/davicasa) to slf4j with almost no efforts and it works fine. Here is the example for slf4j:

Create an annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface InjectLogger {

}
```

Add a SLF4j type listener:

```
public class SLF4JTypeListener implements TypeListener {

    public <T> void hear(TypeLiteral<T> typeLiteral,
            TypeEncounter<T> typeEncounter) {

        // the class which members will be injected
        Class<?> clazz = typeLiteral.getRawType();

        while (clazz != null) {
            //add listener for any field
            Arrays.stream(clazz.getDeclaredFields())
                    .filter(this::isLoggerField)
                    .forEach(
                            f -> typeEncounter
                                    .register(new SLF4JMembersInjector<T>(f)));
            clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
        }
    }

    private boolean isLoggerField(Field f) {
        return f.getType() == Logger.class
                && f.isAnnotationPresent(InjectLogger.class);
    }
}
```

The injector itself:

```
public class SLF4JMembersInjector<T> implements MembersInjector<T> {

    private final Field field;
    private final Logger logger;

    SLF4JMembersInjector(Field field) {

        this.field = field;
        this.logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(field.getDeclaringClass());
        field.setAccessible(true);
    }

    public void injectMembers(T t) {
        try {
            field.set(t, logger);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the binding in my module:

```
bindListener(Matchers.any(), new SLF4JTypeListener());
```

Usage:

```
@InjectLogger
private Logger logger;
```

Comment: Wow this is awesome! Thanks so much!